# org.springframework.cloud:nacos-discovery v0.9.0.RELEASE Enable authentication upgrading nacos 2.3.0. Service startup report: user not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, nacos

org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery v0.9.0.RELEASE Enable authentication when upgrading nacos 2.3.0. Service startup report: user not found!

MSG:
ErrCode:403, ErrMsg:

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Jun 10 15:35:54 GMT+08:00 2023There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).user not found!

---

pom：

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>Greenwich.SR2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-alibaba-dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
  <artifactId>dubbo</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.alibaba.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-config</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</versio
</dependency>
```

---

Can I solve this error without changing the org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery v0.9.0.RELEASE package? How do I need to change the package? Which version can I change to at least to make the project work? The changes are minimal because dubbo is also used in the project